# how to transfer kwargs to uri_for in template

Tags: google-app-engine, jinja2, webapp2

In my template I have:

```
<a href="{{ url_for('named_url', slug=x.slug) }}">x.name</a>
```

In views:

```
webapp2.Route('/smth/<slug>/', handler=SomeHandler, name='named_url'),
```

I get this error:

```
ValueError: URI buiding error: Value "" is not supported for argument "slug".
```

I also tried:

```
<a href="{{ url_for('named_url', slug={{x.slug}}) }}">x.name</a>
```

and

```
<a href="{{ url_for('named_url', slug='{{x.slug}}') }}">x.name</a>
```

but it doesn't work. When I print {{x.slug}} somewhere else in the template it prints the correct slug. Also When I hard code `slug='some_slug'` it also works.

Comment: I didn't realize that some of the entities didn't have slug property.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Inside a template variable, you're pretty much in "Python mode". So you would just use the variables directly, missing out both the braces and the quotes:

```
{{ url_for('named_url', slug=x.slug) }}
```

Comment: It's the first thing I tried, but I get "ValueError: URI buiding error: Value "" is not supported for argument "slug"."

Answer (score 2):

I, too, have experienced this ValueError and (through some trial and error) discovered that it is caused by the specified route definition lacking a regular expression.

In other words, try altering your route to be something like:

```
webapp2.Route('/smth/<slug:.*>/', handler=SomeHandler, name='named_url'),
```